# Work done (by gravity) on paired blocks

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy, work

[image: pulley]

Why does gravity do more work on the block going down?

The total work done (by gravity) on the $8kg$ block is more than the work done (by gravity) on the lighter block. How?

Comment: Ask yourself, what is the direction of gravity on the 8 kg block and in which direction is it moving?

Comment: That's what I was thinking, it's a trick question? 0 work done by gravity as its perpendicular (by inspection) to the direction of motion? The work would be done by the rope?

Comment: Please quote the exact question

Comment: "A 6.00-kg block and an 8.00-kg block are connected as shown. When released, the 6.00-kg block accelerates downward and the 8.00-kg block accelerates to the right. After each block has moved 2.00 cm, the force of gravity has done:" and the answer is: "less work on the 8.00-kg block than on the 6.00-kg block."

Comment: In that case I think it is right to assume that the work done by gravity is zero

Comment: It doesn't sound like a trick question to me.  I also don't see anything wrong with your reasoning.

Answer (score 0):

The OP and Comments give two opposite answers as correct for this question Here's the one I think is correct:

There is a system, consisting of two blocks connected by a rope.

It is initially at rest, and after a period of time, it (all of its parts) is moving.  It has gained kinetic energy, and therefore work has been done on it by an external force.

Both parts of the system are moving at the same speed, whatever it is.  (It could be calculated, but we don't need to do it)

Since both parts have the same speed, the kinetic energy is divided in the ratio of the masses.  The $8$ kg block has $\frac{8}{14}$ of the kinetic energy.

The trick here is that if you are finding the work done by gravity, you don't count potential energy as well.  You'd be double counting the energy.

Consider a simple pendulum;  From one point of view, no work is done, since the total of PE and KE is constant;  it just swaps back and forth.

***OR***

Gravity does work on the pendulum speeding it up on the way down, and the pendulum does work on the earth on the way up.

Either view is correct;  just don't use both...at the same time.